# Can batteries on my RV be brought back to life?

Tags: battery

My 6 V RV batteries were very dry and I added 1 gal. of water to the two of them. Now the sp. gr. is very low (1.1). They are up to 13.4 V on the charger after 4 hrs. It’s in the 30’s today so that may slow down the reactions.

Will the addition of some acid be necessary to get the sp.gr. up?

Comment: I assume you mean 30 **F** (this is an international group) -- it would be nice to _edit your question_ with this tidbit.

Comment: I don't know enough for this to be an _answer_, but unless they leaked they're not missing sulphite -- they're just very severely depleted.  If the batteries were so abused that they needed that much water, then it may be best to just get new ones and start over.  And check your charging system, unless you'd let the thing sit for enough years for evaporation to have caused the low water level.

Comment: How old are they? **Lead-acid** batteries have a life.  Lead-acids are very sensitive to abuse, and "abuse" is pretty much 'looking at them cross-eyed'. If you baby lead-acid, 6-7 years is possible.  You kinda didn't lol..

Answer (score 1):

There are too many variables, most importantly the batteries' age and charging history, to predict the outcome. The only way to know if your batteries will survived this trauma is to bring them to a room with normal room temperature, charge them until they are gassing freely, and then use a high load test apparatus such as a carbon pile tester to see if they maintain voltage under load.

WARNING: A specific gravity of 1.1 means that the acid concentration is about 14% w/w. A sulfuric acid solution at 14% will freeze at -8 degrees C (about 18F). If you are expecting such temperatures, the batteries can freeze, crack, and spill acid when they thaw. I've seen that happen one time, and it was not a pretty sight. These batteries should be brought indoors before it gets that cold.